# ValidateInput(false), but now how to keep my HTML input clean?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, xss

So, in a section of an ASP.NET MVC2 app, I have to allow HTML input from a typical rich textbox. So, I added an attribute on the controller method to turn off MVC's brute-force input validation.

But, now what do I do to prevent XSS attacks. So far, I have looked and found:

- AntiXSS: looks good, but the whitelist seems to not be editable. Also, I am having issues getting it to work, for some reason. After adding the reference to the dll, the compiler still sees a missing assembly.
- Antisamy: allows configuration of a whitelist, but the last time the .NET was updated was in 2009. That doesn't inspire confidence in security software.

What else? Are there other libraries for cleaning up HTML-containing input such that it is easy to configure allowable tags?

Comment: Are you allowed to upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 3? If so you can utilize the AllowHtml attribute.

Comment: That just turns off the brute-force by field instead of by method. But, assuming you let that one filed in unchecked, what then?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an HTML parser, walking along the parse tree eliminating tags/attributes that are harmful. You would have full control of what was allowed. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is the best for C#.